# PHP: [[:<:]] and [[:>:]] anchors

Tags: php, anchor

Why this doesn't work (neither matches nor not), it seems to not parse it.

```
<?php
 echo preg_match("/[[:<:]]name[[:>:]]/","my name is max");
?>
```

It doesn't output neither `0` nor `1`. Why?

Comment: Your code probably returned false. [Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#refsect1-function.preg-match-returnvalues) says: *...or FALSE if an error occurred.* Does your code give any errors?

Comment: What exactly do you want to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have error reporting turned off. If you'd have it enabled you would get the following error:

> **Warning**:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: unknown POSIX class name at offset 3 in ...

This means that you can't have a class name consisting of a less than sign (`[[:<:]]`); give it a proper name instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can replace `[[:<:]]` with `\b` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<?php
 echo preg_match("/name/","my name is max");
?>
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out that error. I know that in your way it matches. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error: Compilation failed: unknown POSIX class name at offset 3